# Get sharepoint metadata inside cells in Excel

Tags: excel, sharepoint

I have a document library in Sharepoint with a lot of custom columns. Some are choices and managed metadata and text. In Word I can use quickparts for viewing the metadata from Sharepoint. But how can we do this in Excel? Quickparts is not available in Excel. I can see all the data coming from Sharepoint in Excel via File -> Info -> Properties -> Show all properties.

But I want to get those properties and put them in cells in the workbook

Answer (score 0):

Excel no longer supports this. It used to, with Excel Services and SharePoint on premises, but it no longer supports this online.

You can edit the properties in Backstage, but none of the tricks with named ranges and linked custom fields that you can see for earlier versions, work any more to link metadata values with Excel cells.

Don't shoot the messenger.

Comment: Ok, do you know if it is possible with office script to fetch document metadata from sharepoint and insert into cells? Can we run office script att document startup?